# Angular ng-animate is not working. Why?

Tags: angularjs, animation

I am adding simple animation in `ng-repeat` and its not working. see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yb58dd6/). Here is my code of angular:

```
var m = angular.module('App', []);

m.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    var i = 0;
    $scope.addItems = function() {
        $scope.items.push("test"+i);
        i++;

    }
});
```

But its working here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VsbrzkZhxDQJv0ZmgSDK?p=preview). Whats wrong with my jsfiddle's code?

Comment: Include jQuery into your jsfiddle

Comment: @OlegYudovich i have tried with adding jquery also its not working.

Answer (score 2):

your `angular` version is different than the working plunker, updating the angular version will solve your problem

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gzL8ez6q/)

But note that this `angular` version is too old, and there is a separate angular module for [`animations`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) in later versions,

---

**with angular 1.4.x**

here is a [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJIzUSWd1zJzB59KDMHD?p=preview) with latest way `angular` version.

include `angular` and `angular-animate` `js` files.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and add the `angular-animate` dependency as,

```
var m = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);
```

and use the `css` classes as,

```
.div.ng-enter {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.div.ng-enter-active {
   -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: because angular versions are not same see the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Serveral issues.

1. ngAngular is not a directive - it is a module

   load the angular-animate.js and define the dependency in your moduel
2. your css selectors do not match the angular naming

   see [ngAnimat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) *classname*.ng-enter / *classname*.ng-leave

```js
var m = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);

m.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  var i = 0;
  $scope.addItems = function() {
    $scope.items.push("test" + i);
    i++;

  }
});
```

```css
.insert.ng-enter {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1000ms;
}
.insert.ng-enter.insert.ng-enter-active {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    opacity:1;
}
.div{
    width:300px;
    padding:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-animate.min.js"></script>


<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl" ng-app='App' class="list">
  <button ng-click="addItems()">Add Items</button>
  <div class="div insert" ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"ngAngular is not a directive"* - you mean `ngAnimate` ?

Comment: @Manwal of course it doesn't work. your angular.js is version 1.2.1 and angular-animate.js is version 1.4 - DON't mix versions!!